# how i can check if there is any other picker view in the superview before adding another one?

Tags: ios, uiview, uipickerview

I have an application in which i am using 3 pickerviews.each with a label and a button.when the button is clicked i want to add a picker view and take the label text from that picker view,then when i am selecting the next button i want to remove the old pickerview and add the new one like that.can anybody help me to achieve this.i did the first part.i have done all this without one part,ie i want to remove the old picker view when i am selecting the new button and need to add the new one.

Answer (score 0):

One solution (out of many possible):

If you have those three UIPickerView objects attached to "`IBOutlet`"'s, you can check to see if they are visible or if they are hidden via the "`hidden`" property.

If one picker is visible, you can retrieved the selected value from it, hide it and then display the next one.